# Need help with JQuery UI Dialog function

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$('#retrieve_password_button').live("click", function(){


if ($('#answer').val() != "") {


    $.post('authentication/questionVerification/' + $('#username_for_question').val() + '/' + $('#answer').val(), function(data){
        if(data != ""){
                $('#retrieved_password_box').text("Your password is : " + data).slideDown('1500');
        }else {
                $('#retrieved_password_box').text("Security answer incorrect").slideDown('1500');                   
        }
    });
    $( "#password_retrieved_dialog" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        width:500,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close" : function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );            
                alert('something'); /*place where I placed my code (jQuery , javascript)

            }
        }
    });
}
})
```

** UPDATE **

It's working now. I tried what @mcgrailm said. But, It other command still not working such as

Comment: Does everything else work without problems? If the `alert` doesn't even work, there might be a syntax issue in your JS.

Comment: where is your redirect code ?

Comment: Are you looking to redirect to another webpage?

Comment: It's working now. I tried what @mcgrailm said. But, It other command still not working such" huh, what ?

Comment: please finish your sentence. But, its other commands are  still not working such as ______.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give us some more code. I just made up a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/nU6E7/
It does not redirect, but maybe you can see something different about this code and yours?

This example redirects: http://jsfiddle.net/nU6E7/1/

Comment: Yes, was just too slow editing my post, look now. I am just trying to help here.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
buttons: {
    'Proced': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            document.location.href = "place/to/go";
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/qMs9M/)